# Can I create a custom keyboard shortcut without a modifier key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I am trying to create a custom keyboard shortcut in System Settings with Ventura 13.2.1, that does not have any modifier key but is rather just a single letter. In many apps and service such as Adobe Illustrator or Google Calendar you can switch on specific tools or change views with a single keystroke, and I would like to replicate this on Apple apps.

In the past, I was able to achieve this by setting a shortcut to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> in the Apple Calendar, and it would come out as just the letter on its own. This let me use a single keystroke and the view would change to week or year, respectively. But for some reason, now that I am using Ventura, this has stopped working — System Settings won’t let me enter <kbd>fn</kbd> plus another key.

Is there some other way to create a single letter shortcut?

Comment: I can't test as I've no Ventura Mac here. You've always been able to use the 10-key [numpad] as single character menu triggers - no Fn needed, just single char. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIFJD.png The Mac has always considered the 10-key numbers as separate to the ones above qwerty, though it doesn't show the difference in the control panel, they are considered separate entities.

Comment: Is there any to create shortcuts that you know of that doesn’t use the numeric keypad? I’m working from a MacBook Air and so… I don’t have a big keyboard!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136439