# Can I set keyboard shortcuts to a single keystroke in app preferences plists?

Tags: keyboard, settings, keybindings, preferences, plist

I would like to set my Mail keyboard shortcuts to single keystroke shortcuts, like how they are in Gmail. For example, I want to set the Archive tool to just <kbd>E</kbd> like in Gmail, but in later macOS versions including Ventura it is not possible to set single-letter shortcuts from within the System Settings app.

I was wondering if it would work to directly edit the preferences plist file for Mail, and I have found it and edited it, but somehow even when I save the plist file, System Settings and Mail still show the default and my shortcut doesn’t work.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make the plist’s contents apply to Mail, and how did the System Settings and Mail menu bar stay the same (as if there is some other file controlling them)?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136439/489896